# Bypass Magento cart on click of regular save button and redirect to onepagecheckout

Tags: magento, cart

I want to bypass the magento cart by clicking on a normal save button which submits the form via ajax and then redirects to onepage checkout by bypassing cart (like using windows.location.href)....please help

Answer (score 0):

Sonam,

You can create an observer for this purpose as follows :

Your config would look something like this:

```
<frontend>
<events>
<checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
         <observers>
         <packagename_modulename_observer>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>packagename_modulename/observer</class>
              <method>addToCartComplete</method>
         </packagename_modulename_observer>
         </observers>
     </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
 </events>
</frontend>
```

You could create an observer listening for the checkout_cart_add_product_complete event and in there you could do something like the following:

```
public function addToCartComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
// Send the user to the Item added page
$response = $observer->getResponse();    
$request = $observer->getRequest();
$response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
}
```

Second and fairer simpler would be :

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/ in CartController.php

Copy this File and search method

```
protected function _goBack()
```

change

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

to

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
```

hope these methods help you complete the process as you want.

Comment: thanks for the replies...i have solved the problem..the problem was not code ...the reason was that the product was disabled ..that is why cart was not showing that product....

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do the same. I recommend SKVs second solution (editing the CartController) but of course you shouldn't edit the core. And overriding a controller is not as simple as, say, overriding a model object.

While you can copy for example `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php`, make your edits and just be done with it, overriding a controller class is not that simple. To the best of my knowledge, you **have** to do it in your own module. Here's what I did.

Made a module: app\code\local\Companyname\Checkout.

Added a etc\config.xml to this module:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Companyname_Checkout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Companyname_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Companyname_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Companyname_Checkout</Companyname_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Added a controllers\CartController.php to my module. This is a copy of the core CartController but I changed

```
class Mage_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
```

to:

```
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Checkout').DS.'CartController.php');
class Pixelkracht_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
```

Finally, make the changes in the _goBack function as suggested by SKV.